# Angular modules href not working

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, http-status-code-404, href

I have an app, the application works with ng server (localhost:4200) but when I deploy it with the command `ng build --env prod --base-href / dashboard2 /` the root does work but the modules indicate 404 error.

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

//Importar componentes
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { UserProfileComponent } from './user-profile/user-profile.component';
import { CreateUserComponent } from './create-user/create-user.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path:'', component: LoginComponent},
    {path:'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
    {path:'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path:'user-profile',   component: UserProfileComponent },
    {path:'create-user', component:CreateUserComponent},
    {path:'home', component: HomeComponent},
    {path:'**', component: LoginComponent}
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Comment: why do you have spaces around dashboard2?

Comment: Wrong writing the line

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command:

```
ng build --prod --base-href /PROJECT_NAME/
```

Comment: www.domain.com/dashboard/user-profile ----- Not Found
The requested URL /dashboard/user-profile was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `PathLocationSTrategy` (default), you need to specify both the base tag and provider for the token `APP_BASE_HREF`. Have you added this line to the `@NgModule` decorator?

`providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/dashboard2'}]`

`APP_BASE_HREF` affects how the router resolves `routerLink` and  `router.navigate()` calls within the app.

The   `<base href="...">` tag affects how the browser resolves URLs when loading static resources like `<link>`, `<script>`, and `<img>`.

Comment: The error was due to that before calling this.router.navigate towards a window.location.reload. Thank you very much